# PostgreSQL Performance Many Partitions in Single vs Multiple Databases

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I'm working with PostgreSQL 11 using declarative partitioning.
I have say 25 partitioned tables and I am dropping partitions by time to provide a rolling window of data retention.
For arguments sake, lets say the sum total partitions for those partitioned tables gets to about 10,000 tables.

Is there any performance difference between having some partitioned tables in different databases versus putting them all in a single database?
E.g. 10k partitions in 1 DB VS 1k partitions in 10 DB

I'm not sure if it makes any difference to PostgreSQL for autovacuums or performance of read queries as the number of partitions grows per database...

Comment: You can't distribute the partitions across databases. All partitions of a single table have to be in the same database

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that is correct. However, the case I'm talking about is more like this: say I have table A, B, & C which I can partition. Is there any difference to partitioning A, B, & C in a single database or putting each in their own database assuming there is NO referential relationship between A, B, & C?

Comment: if you ever want to join those tables you have to put them into one database anyway.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't want to join them. The data is not really related except for the fact that I have to store it. These are several silos of data types that we store and retrieve but NOT inter-related. I'm asking purely from a performance perspective as PostgreSQL is concerned.

Comment: You're asking this question as a theoretical, when it is, in fact, a practical. What's the data size of each table? What sort of machine are you running on? Does "splitting" mean using multiple machines? Are you asking about separate databases in the same cluster, or separate clusters? Are they on separate storage devices with different performance characteristics? .....